# Example of language that does not contain substring $11$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-automata

Let $\Sigma=\{1,0\}$

I just thought of sample strings that can work, such as, $\epsilon, 1, 11, 10, 0, 01$, and came up with:

$$R=1^*(\epsilon+01^*)$$

Is this correct? And is this the correct way to do it? I don't particularly like these questions where they ask you $x$ is **not** a substring. How do we even do those?

Comment: Are you sure that the string $11$ is allowed ? And $1^*$ is certainly not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question is misleading. I suppose you are interesting in the language of all words not containing $11$ as a substring. More generally, given a word $u$, the set of words containing $u$ as a substring is the language
$$
L(u) = \Sigma^*u\Sigma^*
$$
Therefore, the set of words not containing $u$ as a substring is the complement of $L(u)$. If you want a regular expression for this language, you can proceed as follows

1. First compute the minimal DFA of $L(u)$ (this automaton has $|u| + 1$ states).
2. Compute the minimal DFA of its complement (just swap the final states and the non final ones).
3. Compute a regular expression from the resulting DFA.

For your example, $u = 11$, the minimal automaton of $L(11)$ is

[image: The minimal automaton of $L(11)$]

and the minimal automaton of its complement is

[image: The minimal automaton of its complement]

It is now easy to get a regular expression for the language accepted by this automaton: $(0 + 10)^*(\varepsilon + 1)$.

Comment: What are the accepting states? Usually they are drawn with double circle but I don't see any in yours so you might be using another notation. What are the accpeting states in both automatas?

Answer (score 0):

As the substring $11$ is forbidden, any $1$ must be followed by a $0$ or nothing. So a good candidate is

$$(0+10)^*(\epsilon+1)$$ a little more symmetrically written $$((\epsilon+1)0)^*(\epsilon+1).$$

There are many more ways to avoid $11$, such as with the trivial $0^*$.

Comment: Does the $|$ refer to or?

Comment: @KSplitX: yep. I have turned it to a $+$.

Comment: How would you alter this answer if instead I said $111$ is forbidden? Well then any $1$ can be followed by another $1$, but that $1$ **must** be followed by a $0$. I think it would be $R=(110+0)^*(11+10+0^*)(1+\epsilon)$, what do you think?

Comment: @KSplitX: your regexpr allows $110000111$.

Comment: $$((\epsilon+1+11)0)^*(\epsilon+1+11)$$